# How to delete rows from a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of 10 rows of which I want to delete 5 of them,(from 5-10) how can I do this? Tried a few ALTER And modify queries but nothing worked...was just guess work.

Comment: Were you using `a few ALTER And modify queries` to insert these 10 row as well, then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the rows with `id`s between 5 and 10 (both inclusive, that is *6* rows, not 5), you can simply do a simple `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select * from t;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
+----+

mysql> delete from t order by id desc limit 5;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```